# What is the main page for laravel voyager, when i don't use serve?

Tags: laravel, voyager

I'm programming an app in my own server. I will have to migrate it to an Internet web server and I don't have access to ssh. I can't launch serve.
So I have to know how to launch voyager main page (I know how to do that just with laravel).
Any site where I can find information about?
Help will be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of hosting environment are you using? `php artisan serve` is only ment for local development and not for production environments.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that it's only ment for local development. Linux and managing it with cpanel, shared, so I don't have access to ssh, that's because right now I'm using my own server, XAMPP. I know that I can move .htaccess, an rename serve.php, when I use only laravel, but can not find how I do the same thing with voyager, so I start at voyager's login page. Thanks a lot for your answer.